# Ordered sets. Let $(A, \le_A)$ and $(B, \le_B)$ be ordered sets.

Tags: order-theory

Let $(A, \le_A)$ and $(B, \le_B)$ be ordered sets.

(a) Prove or disprove: if both $A$ and $B$ are dense, then so is $A \times B$ with
the product ordering

(b) Prove or disprove: if both $A$ and $B$ are dense, then so is $A \times B$ with
the lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Product ordering: this is the ordering on A × B given by (x, y) ≤ (x
′
, y′
) iff x ≤ x
′ and y ≤ y
′
.
• Lexicographic ordering: this is another ordering on A × B given by (x, x′
) ≤ (y, y′
) iff x < x′ or
x = x
′ and y ≤ y
′
.